# I need assistance creating a proper localstorage to correctly remember fairly complex toggle state

Tags: jquery, css, storage, toggle

I have a multilevel toggle code that I need to have remembered when a user refreshes the page. I have read others here but unfortunately they are all single level toggles and they do not help me. The toggle works perfect without any of my localstorage code added. However, when I add the localstorage code the original code goes haywire. Can anyone guide me to the correct way to set up my localstorage? https://jsfiddle.net/gu73x16s/

I have tried several methods and I am unable to get any to work. I will attach a jsfiddle.

```
enter code here
<form method="post" autocomplete="on">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
  <p><label class="yes_text">Yes</label><span><input type="radio"  
   id="dog" name="answer_name"
value="yes"></span></p>
  <p><label>No</label><span><input type="radio"  name="answer_name"                       

checked="checked"></span></p>
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="include_other_levels">
<div class="red">
  <div>
    <p>Include Red Dogs&#58;</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><label class="yes_text_include">select to include</label><span>                                                       
   <input type="checkbox"
id="cat" class="red" name="red_name" value=""></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="green">
  <div>
    <p>Include Green Dogs&#58;</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><label>select to include</label><span><input type="checkbox"                         
    name="green_name"
value=""></span></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</fieldset>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(this).find('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
$(this).closest('form').find('label');
if (this.value == "yes") {
  $(this).closest('form').find(".include_other_levels").toggle(200);
  localStorage.setItem("toggleState", "d");
} else {
  $(this).closest('form').find(".include_other_levels").toggle(200);
  $("div.green").hide();
  localStorage.setItem("toggleState", "g");
}
});
var state = localStorage.getItem("toggleState");
if (state == "d") {
$(".yes_text").addClass("toggle");
$("#dog").prop("checked", true);
$(".include_other_levels").show()
} else {
$(".yes_text").addClass("goggle");
$("#dog").prop("checked", false);
}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {

if ($("input.red:checkbox").is(':checked')) {
  $('div.green').show(300);
} else {
  $('div.green').hide(300);
}
});

});


 fieldset.include_other_levels {
 display: none;
 clear: both;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

The code has an initial radio button. If user selects "yes" they get a dropdown checkbox. If the user checks that checkbox another checkbox dropsdown. Each state needs to have storage so the user can return after a page refresh and the same state appears.

Comment: Maybe it will help https://jsfiddle.net/tomik23/ovysmutL/

Comment: Hello Grzegorz T., Thanks, this looks pretty good but it only works one time through. Is there anyway to keep it consistent? The first time through it looks great. The second time through all the checkboxes open at the same time. They are suppose to work in steps. Radio yes --> first checkbox --> second checkbox. In reverse if the first checkbox is unselected the second one clears and hides. I am not sure how to manipulate the localstorage to save their location and keep the code intact. I hope I am clear enough to be understood. Can this be achieved?

Comment: Next version, this time the delay with clicking. Clicked on the parent element removes the selection from parents checkboxes https://jsfiddle.net/tomik23/ovysmutL/4/

Comment: Hello Grzegorz T., I am now getting an alert message every time I click back on the "no". The alert is; "Confirm To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier." Is it not possible to achieve a localstorage without these quirks?

Comment: Is this the last version :) https://jsfiddle.net/tomik23/ovysmutL/5/

Comment: WOW, this is awesome! The only problem I am having now is trying to integrate it back into the webpage. It is messing with the checkboxes in other forms now. Can I utilize "(this).closest('form').find "somewhere? I see that you used a grave accent. I have never seen this in code. What does it do? Does it need to be changed while it is in the webpage?

Comment: A new code to use, unfortunately I can not take the time anymore. You can now add as many forms as you like :) https://jsfiddle.net/tomik23/ovysmutL/7/

Comment: Hello, I have been working on the last version jsfiddle.net/tomik23/ovysmutL/7 . However, I am unable to get it to function on my end. It works perfect in jfiddle. Of course I added the doc.ready function. The problem that is occuring happens when the localstorage loads the state in after the page refreshes. It loads everything then unchecks the checkboxes. For the life of me I can not figure out what is going on with the code. Is this something that can be corrected? thanks